# ie6 float:right display:inline-block(display:inline)

Tags: internet-explorer-6, css-float

How to fix `display:inline-block(display:inline)` with `float:right` in `ie6`?

code in: http://jsfiddle.net/VGaGt/

html

```
<div>
    text<span>>></span>
</div>​
```

css

```
div{
    float:left; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px; 
    padding:5px;
    background:#ccc;
}
span{
    float:right;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    cursor: pointer;
}​
```

Comment: Can we know what is the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: @freebird, I copy the code to jsfiddle, you could test in your ie6, the `span` is in a new line. but I need the span inside the `div`, after the word `text` with `float:right`.

Comment: Ya I tested and got the problem,is it working fine in IE higher versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your text takes on the width of the entire div in IE6, which is why span breaks the line. One option is to wrap the text in a p tag, float it to the left and control its width by setting width to 200px or something like that.

HTML

```
<div>
  <p>text</p><span>>></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
p {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YuQHx/1/).